# Sync local git repo with new github repository

Tags: git, github

I have a local git repository hosted in local sever.I would like to add the project to github repository. I would like to keep my local repository as the main repository and github repo as backup repo.

Is it possibly to keep the history(commit history) when I'm adding project to the github?

I would like to "push" every commit to local git repository, so can I sync all the local repo pushes with github repo?

If above two possible, how could I achieve?, If there are link which I could refer?

Udeshika

Comment: I think you might need a perusal of [the Git website](http://git-scm.com/).  It'll help to straighten out any confusions you have like this one, as what you're asking for is fairly entry-level Git information.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you want to push existing git repository to Github

https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/

Create a new github repo, copy its link and add the remote to your local repository.

```
git remote add origin <remoteRepoUrl>
```

Then push your local git branch to Github. I am assuming it is master branch.

```
git push origin master
```

Comment: Thank you - the confusing thing was that the help doc you linked is supposed to be for "an existing project", but that page instructs you to initialise a new local repository. This answer cleared that up.